# AWS delegation policy error: "This resource-based policy contains invalid JSON"

Tags: json, amazon-web-services

This seems to valid through the UI, but I get the above error when I try to add this delegation policy:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {},
            "Action": [
                "organizations:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Principal seems fishy.

Comment: tried changing to `"Principal": {
       "AWS": 8944352*****
   },` and its the same error

Comment: An example is: `"Principal": { "AWS": "123456789012" }`. What are you actually trying to attach this policy to? And how are you supplying it (awscli, SDK)?

Comment: using the aws online portal here: https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/organizations/v2/home/settings/resource-policy... and it doesn't work with any version of principal I try, same error.

Comment: when I try to add all the actions individually, it give me a different error: `This resource-based policy contains an unsupported action.`... seems like only these are options? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_delegate_policies.html?icmpid=docs_orgs_console

Comment: After providing a valid Principal, was the error message still "This resource-based policy contains invalid JSON"? I'd hope not.

Answer (score 4):

Seems that only [certain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_delegate_policies.html?icmpid=docs_orgs_console) privileges are possible, even though the UI allows you to select all... here's what I ended up with. Also, as @jarmod said, you have to specify the "Principal"

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "8944352*****"
            },
            "Action": [
                "organizations:AttachPolicy",
                "organizations:CreatePolicy",
                "organizations:DeletePolicy",
                "organizations:DeletePolicy",
                "organizations:DescribeAccount",
                "organizations:DescribeCreateAccountStatus",
                "organizations:DescribeEffectivePolicy",
                "organizations:DescribeHandshake",
                "organizations:DescribeOrganization",
                "organizations:DescribeOrganizationalUnit",
                "organizations:DescribePolicy",
                "organizations:DescribeResourcePolicy",
                "organizations:DetachPolicy",
                "organizations:DisablePolicyType",
                "organizations:EnablePolicyType",
                "organizations:ListAccounts",
                "organizations:ListAccountsForParent",
                "organizations:ListAWSServiceAccessForOrganization",
                "organizations:ListChildren",
                "organizations:ListCreateAccountStatus",
                "organizations:ListDelegatedAdministrators",
                "organizations:ListDelegatedServicesForAccount",
                "organizations:ListHandshakesForAccount",
                "organizations:ListHandshakesForOrganization",
                "organizations:ListOrganizationalUnitsForParent",
                "organizations:ListParents",
                "organizations:ListPolicies",
                "organizations:ListPoliciesForTarget",
                "organizations:ListRoots",
                "organizations:ListTagsForResource",
                "organizations:ListTargetsForPolicy",
                "organizations:TagResource",
                "organizations:UntagResource",
                "organizations:UpdatePolicy"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```